# Reading a data source for bulk letters

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word, mailmerge

I have written a macro in VBA to seperate bulk letters and to save them as pdf documents.
Using a built-in datasource in Word ( Access database i think ) for testing purposes works fine here. But as I try to use other datasources like .txt or .csv, the macro only saves the first entry of the bulk letter. I already figured out that the problem is the Datasource RecordCount. I displayed

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
```

and the result was `-1` although there are about 30 entries.

The bulk letters in Word itself are displayed as they should; all entries are there. The format of the datasource is simple csv like this:

```
employeenr; title; firstname; name;
5000001   ; Dr.  ; Max      ; Must;
5000002   ;      ; Rita     ; Rat ;
```

So what could be the problem of VBA not reading the datasource correctly if it's already done by word? Are there some special restrictions for data sources and there formats?

In case it's needed, here the part of the code where it iterates through the datasource:

```
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    .DataSource.ActiveRecord = 1
    Do
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = .ActiveRecord
            .LastRecord = .ActiveRecord
            sBrief = Path & .DataFields("employeenr").Value & "_" & Data & ".pdf"
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False

        If .DataSource.DataFields("employeenr").Value > "" Then
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=sBrief, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
        End If
        ActiveDocument.Close False

        If .DataSource.ActiveRecord < .DataSource.RecordCount Then
            .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: Try first moving to the last record `.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastDataSourceRecord` and see if you can get the recordcount by reading from `.DataSource.ActiveRecord`

Comment: This problem arises when Word uses ODBC/OLE DB providers that do not return a record count (which in some cases it makes sense not to do, as something else can be adding records while Word is reading them). If the suggestion by Tim Williams does not work, I will post another method.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. And also interesting to know why the RecordCount did not work for this datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few problems in your code
The lines

```
.DataSource.ActiveRecord = 1
And 
  If .DataSource.ActiveRecord < .DataSource.RecordCount Then
```

Does not take filtering and selections into account.

The correct code looks like this

```
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord
    LastRecord = .DataSource.ActiveRecord

    .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord
    Do
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = .ActiveRecord
            .LastRecord = .ActiveRecord
            sBrief = Path & .DataFields("employeenr").Value & "_" & Data & ".pdf"
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False

        If .DataSource.DataFields("employeenr").Value > "" Then
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=sBrief, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
        End If
        ActiveDocument.Close False

        If .DataSource.ActiveRecord < LastRecord Then
            .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
   End With
```